# Wrapping a C++ library in Python that calls the Python C API

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

C++ library is wrapped in Python using SWIG. We can instantiate a class in Python and when we call a method in this class which uses a Python C API this error comes up:

Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6

If we insert Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS before calling Python in C then the error turns into a Segmentation fault.

It seems this is a problem with Python calling C which calls Python, no? Any ideas?

Comment: Is SWIG up to date? Are you using any custom typemaps we should know about?

Comment: I'm using SWIG Version 2.0.11 and no custom typemaps

Comment: Could you post a SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling python from C you need to ensure the GIL is locked using `PyGILState_Ensure()` and after the call you can release the GIL using `PyGILState_Release()`. For more:

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html?highlight=gil#PyGILState_Ensure